# Garden light connected to main lounge light stopped working

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, cable-management

I have recently moved into a new property and all light fittings came with no shaders/were pretty basic. I have then proceeded to (safely) remove the light fitting of the living room, replaced it with a proper pendant lamp, and reattached it. It works well.

However, since doing this a floodlight in the garden (sensor activated, halogen) stopped working. The floodlight comes with a switch to turn it off completely, I checked it is in ON position and the bulb is not damaged (tested it on a different lamp).

The builders confirmed the circuit/cabling of the garden floodlight is connected to the one in the living room but refused to articulate any further.

A look at the living room light fitting shows the current situation:

[image: Fitting display]

To illustrate better, here are the cables getting IN the eight holes (pardon the terminology):

BLUE (to lightbulb) BLUE empty   empty BROWN BROWN    BLUE BROWN (to lightbulb)

There are also two spare cables, one blue, one brown, hanging forlornly by the side:

[image: leftover cables]

I half suspect these may be those giving electricity to the outdoor light, but as I have done enough damage with my first intervention, I turn to you for any indication of what may be wrong with this/where I should place those two leftover cables.

Thank you for any help!

***Edit:*** I am in the UK.

Comment: If you let us know what country you are in someone from that country may know better how to help you. I am guessing here but, the blue wire goes with the blues and the brown with the browns. There are two terminals with screws that are backed out. One blue, one brown.

Comment: @ArchonOSX thank you - edited the OP to add I am living in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the outdoor light is on a sensor, which means it just needs a constant supply of power and handles switching itself. If this cable hanging down is in fact the supply to the outdoor light then connect the blue cable into one of the far left block of 3 (that also has an existing blue cable connected) and the brown into the central blocks (in your picture it has 2 brown connections). In a ceiling rose the two blocks of 3 are the constant supply and the single block of 2 is for the switched supply. So you will effectively be providing a constant supply to wherever this cable is going.

If the garden light still doesn't work then unplug it and get someone in, it may have been unplugged for a reason!